# batch file write empty file

Tags: c#, batch-file

I write unit test. The code call cmd with parameters and write result to file. But in result this is file is empty. Can you help me fix it?

```
String command = @"tf workspaces /owner:* /computer:* /server:http://servertfs:8080/tfs/Default/  > C:\Test\test1.txt";
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = command;
using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
{
    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: What is tf?  Is it an executable?  If it is, then you should be using tf.exe instead of cmd.exe

Comment: tf it's tfs program. It's noraml work with this command. But nothing set to output file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the [`ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx) to `true` and then get the output via [`Process.StandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) instead of appending `> C:\Test\test1.txt` to the command.

```
String command = @"tf workspaces /owner:* /computer:* /server:http://servertfs:8080/tfs/Default/";
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = command;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
{
    string output = exeProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

You can put the output to the desired file or use it directly.

Comment: Unfortunately variable output is empty

Comment: It is possible, that the program doesn't use standard streams. What is happening if the command `tf workspaces /owner:* /computer:* /server:http://servertfs:8080/tfs/Default/ > C:\Test\test1.txt` is executed in the console?

Comment: Change cmd.exe to tf.exe and remove tf from the arguments.

Comment: No. This way also give empty result.

Comment: Which way exactly? Execute from the console?

Comment: I return to cmd. Manual execute perfect work. But execute from Visual Studio give empty result (I think, it's bad credential. My unit test, which execute batch file, work on build server.)